# How can I open the .docx file stored in Google Drive with Google Doc?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I upload a .docx file to [a directory in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tybocGBO3vjSRjfK1CqOz36TOLhu46Gw?usp=sharing), and can't find an option to open it with Google Doc, when right clicking it. How can I open the .docx file stored in Google Drive with Google Doc?

In the screenshot, the .docx file seems not recognized by Google Doc.
(I have chosen app DocHub, but it is not Google Doc. I remember Google Doc can work with .docx files.)

(I share the directory on Google drive with others, and we will edit the files there and create new files there.)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Checkout [Work with Microsoft Office files](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308757?hl=en). If you need further help, please show that you tried to follow the instructions of the referred help article and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: While I thank you for the link, my post showed exactly it doesn't work. Am I not following your rule or is my post not being read?

Comment: It doesn't as it doesn't show that you are using Chrome, uninstalled the referred extension, etc.

Comment: I don't have the extensions mentioned in the link installed in Chromium browser

Comment: OK. Anyway, you should mention that you are using Chromium, not Chrome. P.S. Chromium is not the same as Chrome.

Comment: I want to emphasize that the browser is not the problem. I have tried in both browsers. Neither have the extensions mentioned in the link.

Comment: I emphasize that the more relevant information that you include directly in the question your post will be better and will have more chances to get answers. P.S. Not all users like to follow links to externals pages).

Comment: It is not relevant information

Answer (score 1):

I figured out an awkward workaround.

1. upload the docx file to Google Doc, which converts the file to google document type
2. in Google Doc, File->Move the file to the directory in Google Drive.

It is not as direct and convenient as  a hypothetical way where we can upload the file to Google Drive and make the file recognizable by Google Doc. ("hypothetical", because I don't know how to do that.)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue when uploading a `.docx` file from Linux created in LibreOffice and was able to workaround this by removing the `.docx` extension from the file. I'm guessing that for some reason this seems to trigger some sort of 'auto detection' of the file type in Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

The file type is Unknown File. You have to fix that first.

[image]

You might try to upload the file again, or if are able to use Google Apps Script / Google Drive API make a copy and set the correct MIME type to it.

Resources

- [How to change mimeType of a file in Google Drive using the REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48916708/1595451)
- [Change Mime Type of Uploaded PDFs in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38013346/1595451)

Comment: Thanks. The link you gave in comment is exactly to show MS Office word file work in Google Drive and Google Doc. So do .docx files  work with Google Doc?

Comment: I am not familiar with API. Could you provide specific steps to modify its mime type? (I know a little about curl and can pick up other command line tools in Linux). Thanks

Comment: Does Google Drive not have a UI feature for that purpose? Do I have to use API?

Comment: Which MIME type do you change the file to that will work? Could you verify your solution and provide specific steps with commands?